# Why doesn't a call to free() reduce the size of the heap?

Tags: c, memory-management

We know that the stack of a program will grow or shrink when it runs.  In a C program, when we use `malloc()` to allocate memory, if current memory is not enough, it will call `sbrk()` to extend the heap size.  When we use `free()` to release allocated memory, it doesn't shrink the heap.  Why doesn't it make sense to shrink the heap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack does *not* shrink. Your *use* of the stack may be variable but the stack itself generally stays constant in size.

And you *can* shrink the heap by calling `sbrk` with a negative argument but I suspect the main reason that's not done is because the process may need the memory again at some point. It can take time to adjust the `malloc` arena(s) when the underlying memory changes.

When you need more memory, that's fine, you pay the price because you want something. But you don't want to pay that price when releasing memory since you don't *need* to. And, if you did, then needed that memory again, you'd be constantly paying the price. Think of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    char *m = malloc (1000000);
    free (m);
}
```

and think of how much more inefficient that would be with the extra load.

You can think of the memory freed but not released back to the operating system as your own personal cache of memory.

This is all assuming, of course, that `malloc` uses `sbrk` at all. Modern operating systems may provide better alternatives due to the disconnect between logical and physical memory.

Comment: Thank you. you mean that the stack itself is constant, the use of stack is variable. It's the space locality that we usually don't shrink the memory, because we may need the memory again(actually you can do it by call sbrk with a negative argument)

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for memory (using `malloc` for example) it has two choices:

- If it already has enough space "reserved" it just gives you that memory
- If not it goes and asks the operating system (using a system call)

When you `free` the memory, the same mechanism keeps it around, in case you ask for it later. Constantly bothering the OS by asking for memory / relinquishing memory wouldn't be efficient.

Obviously, since you are talking about C, it is worth mentioning that no standard will ever enforce any such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In general it doesn't make a lot of sense to use `sbrk()` in the first place, these days.  For a more in depth discussion of that function, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076532/how-does-sbrk-work-in-c).