# Why using both malloc/calloc/realloc and brk functions will results in undefined behavior?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc, brk

Does this means using one of (malloc or calloc or realloc) and one of(brk/sbrk) concurrently results in UB or using both malloc and calloc can also cause UB?

This happends through the entire program or just a source file?

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: I think the general recommendation is to avoid using `brk` and `sbrk`.  The `malloc` family of functions uses them, and should normally suffice for your memory allocation needs.

Comment: It's in my machine organization class I studied today

Comment: "...using both malloc and calloc can also cause UB?" No malloc and calloc in the same program is fine. No problem. It's only a problem if you also use brk/sbrk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does sbrk() work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076532/how-does-sbrk-work-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

The actual rule, on systems that have both `sbrk` and `malloc`, is "The implementation of `malloc` may assume that no code other than itself calls `sbrk` with a nonzero argument."

Phrased this way, the consequences are much easier to deduce:

- There must be only one operational implementation of `malloc` per process. (On systems like this, the OS-provided C library's `malloc` is *usually* designed to notice and gracefully step aside when you supply another implementation.)
- It is fine to call `sbrk(0)` anywhere you want.
- If you are writing an implementation of `malloc`, you may go right ahead and call `sbrk` with a nonzero argument, and assume that nobody else will.
- But if you are *not* writing an implementation of `malloc`, calling `sbrk` with a nonzero argument will probably cause the next call to `malloc` (or any function that calls `malloc` internally, which could be any of them except those documented as async-signal-safe) to crash the process or corrupt the heap.

  It should be easy to see why calling `sbrk` with a *negative* argument, from outside the `malloc` implementation, can have this effect. You shrank the heap! There might have been allocations in the space that you took away! There almost certainly *are* internal `malloc` bookkeeping structures in there!

  Why calling `sbrk` with a *positive* argument can have the same effect is more subtle. `malloc` won't know about the additional space. The next time `malloc` calls `sbrk` itself, it will update its internal bookkeeping structures incorrectly. There will be a chunk of memory in the middle of the heap that it's not able to track. It's very likely to scribble on that memory and/or confuse itself into accessing addresses *outside* the heap.

Comment: See also this post, [How does sbrk() work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076532/) which has some decent answers.