# How to program a malloc() implementation with correct pointer alignment in C

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I'm currently trying to recode my own implementation of `malloc()` in C language. I followed several tutorials but each time the pointer alignment was inccorect (aligned to a power of 4) but according to the ABI it is necessary for `malloc()` to return a pointer aligned to a power of 8. So I re-adapted one. I recoded `malloc()`, `free()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `reallocf()`.

When testing `malloc()` I get silent errors with valgrind. When testing further (multiple calls to `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()`) I get a segfault.

Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct block_s *block_t;

    struct block_s {
        size_t size;
        block_t next;
        block_t prev;
        int free;
        void *ptr;
        char data[1];
    };


#define BLOCK_SIZE 36

#define align8(x) (((((x) - 1) >> 3) << 3) + 8)

void *base = NULL;

block_t get_block(void *p)
{
    char *tmp;
    tmp = p;
    return (p = tmp -= BLOCK_SIZE);
}

int valid_addr(void *p)
{
    if (base) {
        if (p > base && p < sbrk(0))
            return (p == (get_block(p))->ptr);
    }
    return (0);
}

block_t fusion(block_t b)
{
    if (b->next && b->next->free) {
        b->size += BLOCK_SIZE + b->next->size;
        b->next = b->next->next;
        if (b->next)
            b->next->prev = b;
    }
    return (b);
}

void split_block(block_t b, size_t s)
{
    block_t new;
    new = (block_t) b->data + s;
    new->size = b->size - s - BLOCK_SIZE;
    new->next = b->next;
    new->prev = b;
    new->free = 1;
    new->ptr = new->data;
    b->size = s;
    b->next = new;
    if (new->next)
        new->next->prev = new;
}

block_t find_block(block_t *last, size_t size)
{
    block_t b = sbrk(0);
    while (b && !(b->free && b->size >= size))
    {
        *last = b;
        b = b->next;
    }
    return (b);
}

block_t extend_heap(block_t last, size_t s)
{
    int64_t sb;
    block_t b;
    b = sbrk(0);
    sb = (size_t) sbrk(BLOCK_SIZE + s);
    if (sb < 0)
        return (NULL);
    b->size = s;
    b->next = NULL;
    b->prev = last;
    b->ptr = b->data;
    if (last) {
        last->next = b;
    }
    b->free = 0;
    return (b);
}

void copy_block(block_t src, block_t dest)
{
    size_t *sdata, *ddata;
    size_t i;
    sdata = src->ptr;
    ddata = dest->ptr;
    for (i = 0; (i * 8) < src->size && (i * 8) < dest->size; i++)
        ddata[i] = sdata[i];
}

void my_free(void *p)
{
    block_t b;
    if (valid_addr(p)) {
        b = get_block(p);
        b->free = 1;
        if (b->prev && b->prev->free) {
            b = fusion(b->prev);
        }
        if (b->next) {
            fusion(b);
        } else {
            if (b->prev)
                b->prev->next = NULL;
            else
                base = NULL;
            brk(b);
        }
    }
}

void *my_malloc(size_t size)
{
    block_t b, last;
    size_t s;
    s = align8(size);
    if (base) {
        last = base;
        b = find_block(&last, s);
        if (b) {
            if ((b->size - s) >= (BLOCK_SIZE + 8))
                split_block(b, s);
            b->free = 0;
        } else {
            b = extend_heap(last, s);
            if (!b)
                return (NULL);
        }
    } else {
        b = extend_heap(NULL, s);
        if (!b)
            return (NULL);
        base = b;
    }
    return (b->data);
}

void *my_calloc(size_t number, size_t size)
{
    size_t *new, s8, i;
    new = my_malloc(number * size);
    if (new) {
        s8 = align8(number * size) << 3;
        for (i = 0; i < s8; i++)
            new[i] = 0;
    }
    return (new);
}

void *my_realloc(void *p, size_t size)
{
    size_t s;
    block_t b, new;
    void *newp;
    if (!p) {
        return (my_malloc(size));
    }
    if (valid_addr(p)) {
        s = align8(size);
        b = get_block(p);
        if (b->size >= s) {
            if (b->size - s >= (BLOCK_SIZE + 8)) {
                split_block(b, s);
            }
        } else {
            if (b->next && b->next->free && (b->size + BLOCK_SIZE + b->next->size) >= 5) {
                fusion(b);
                if (b->size - s >= (BLOCK_SIZE + 8)) {
                    split_block(b, s);
                }
            } else {
                newp = my_malloc(s);
                if (!newp) {
                    return (NULL);
                }
                new = get_block(newp);
                copy_block(b, new);
                my_free(p);
                return (newp);
            }
        }
        return (p);
    }
    return (NULL);
}

void *my_reallocf(void *p, size_t size)
{
    void *newp;
    newp = my_realloc(p, size);
    if (!newp)
        my_free(p);
    return (newp);
}
```

Here is the malloc's test code :

```c
int main(void)
{
    char *str = my_malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
    str = strcpy(str, "Hello World!\0");
    printf("# Malloc test\nString %p = %s\n", str, str);
    my_free(str);
}
```

And here's the valgrind report:

```bash
==56698== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==56698== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==56698== Using Valgrind-3.21.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==56698== Command: ./build/my_malloc
==56698== 
==56698== Invalid write of size 8
==56698==    at 0x1098B3: main (my_malloc.c:214)
==56698==  Address 0x403502d is in the brk data segment 0x4035000-0x4035033
==56698== 
==56698== Invalid read of size 1
==56698==    at 0x4847ED4: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:501)
==56698==    by 0x48E36E8: __printf_buffer (vfprintf-process-arg.c:435)
==56698==    by 0x48E3E51: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1523)
==56698==    by 0x48D92FE: printf (printf.c:33)
==56698==    by 0x1098D9: main (my_malloc.c:215)
==56698==  Address 0x4035034 is 0 bytes after the brk data segment limit 0x4035034
==56698== 
# Malloc test
String 0x4035028 = Hello World!
==56698== 
==56698== HEAP SUMMARY:
==56698==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==56698==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==56698== 
==56698== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==56698== 
==56698== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==56698== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Also, I noticed that Valgrind returned erroneous values (on allocated and freed memory) during my various tests... I have no hypotheses on this subject.

The choice not to use `mmap()` is deliberate.

I'd also like to point out that my dynamic memory allocator is intended for an environment where the standard C library is absent.

My hypothesis is that I'm miscalculating the block size and/or misaligning my pointers.

By changing the `BLOCK_SIZE` to 44, the test with a simple malloc / free works, but as soon as there are several it segfault.

Can you tell me how to make this allocator work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would your implementation be different for 64-bit than 32-bit?

Comment: @Barmar I've read that for 32-bit systems, pointers must be aligned to a power of 4 and for 64-bit systems to a power of 8.

Comment: Good point. That seems like it should be a really minor change.

Comment: With `char data[1];` you may have an off by one issue. It might be easier with `char data[];`

Comment: Actually, even in a 32-bit build you should probably still align to 8 byte boundaries so that doubles are naturally aligned.

Comment: Your malloc does not replace the C library's malloc and therefore *you are not allowed to call sbrk with a nonzero argument*. You must use mmap instead. That might not be your only bug, but it's very likely to be the one causing you to crash inside `printf`.

Comment: Also, every pointer returned by `malloc` must be aligned to the alignment requirement of `max_align_t`. You are returning pointers with only half that alignment. Also, your `BLOCK_SIZE` constant is smaller than `sizeof(struct block_s) - 1`.

Comment: @zwol Yes. 36%8 != 0. (easy to think of 8 bytes)... Suggestion for Virgil... `long long` can store a very big number, both positive and negative... Perhaps rework this removing the 8 bytes needed for the boolean `free`. When a block is `free()`'d, merely set its size to be 0-size... Use the sign bit of `long long size` to mark free blocks (including their size expressed as a negative)... Then your header should be only 32 bytes, not 36... Two adjacent blocks with negative sizes could be "fused"...

Comment: Did you replace _all_ OS allocating functions? When I did a similar thing I realized I had a shitload of (to me unknown at that point) companion functions I also had to implement.

Comment: @Virgil G. Wouldn't the memory blocks need 64-bit alignment on 32-bit system too given the existence of 64-bit types (e.g. `double` and `long long`).

Comment: Why are you *calculating* the block size instead of using `sizeof`?

Comment: @zwol My implementation of malloc() is intended for use in an environment where there is no standard C library. I'm trying out different values for `BLOCK_SIZE` and I'm looking for just the right one.

Comment: @VirgilG. Sure, but to test it in a hosted environment (gcc+glibc is a hosted environment) you have to play by the hosting C library's rules, which in this case includes "[only the C library's malloc is allowed to call sbrk with a nonzero argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527668/why-using-both-malloc-calloc-realloc-and-brk-functions-will-results-in-undefined/75528212#75528212)."  You shouldn't need to "try out different values" for `BLOCK_SIZE`; there is one correct value and you can _compute_ that value from `sizeof(struct block_s) - 1` and `alignof(max_align_t)`.

Comment: @zwol Okay, but how do you test in a glibc-free environment? I tested with `-nostdlib` and added the ASM code to execute `main()` but I get an execution error like "wrong ELF class".

Comment: You should ask a new question about that (as I see you did)