# C++ header files changes program break

Tags: c++, c, linux, malloc, abi

I can't understand why this code prints different program breaks

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int max_size = 1024;
    char* ptr[max_size];

    int blockCount = 1000;
    int blockSize = 4*1024*1024;
    int from = 1;
    int to = blockCount;
    int step = 1;
    int i;

    printf("Program break: 0x%p\n", sbrk(0));
    for(i = 0; i < blockCount; ++i)
    {
        ptr[i] = (char*)malloc(blockSize);
    }

    printf("Program break: 0x%p\n", sbrk(0));
    for(int i = from; i < to; i += step)
    {
        free((char*)ptr[i]);
    }

    printf("Program break: 0x%p\n", sbrk(0));
}
```

The output:

```
Program break: 0x0x5604211f1000
Program break: 0x0x560421212000
Program break: 0x0x560421212000
```

But if I prepend an `#include <iostream>` at the beginning of the file it prints the same program break.

The output:

```
Program break: 0x0x556617053000
Program break: 0x0x556617053000
Program break: 0x0x556617053000
```

Does it change the program break in headers ?
If so what can possibly change the program break in a header file ?
Also if compiled as a C code the last program break points to the initial. As if `free` returns the pages which are not used.
But in C++ case it doesn't happen.

g++ version: 9.4.0

Compile options: -O0

OS/ABI: UNIX - System V

ABI Version: 0

Kernel version: 5.15.0-87-generic

Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: For example `std::cout` is a global object, I would say it is likely it allocates some buffers on creation.

Comment: Anyway, you can trace `sbrk` or `malloc` and see who and why calls it.

Comment: @Quimby, Yes but how much is that memory ? You see, if one "malloc"s so much memory program break should change. The allocations for C++ global objects are done during __start

Comment: what exactly is the question? Why the code you posted prints different values? Why the same value is printed when you include `<iostream>` ? Why the behavior is different in C? I suggest you narrow down the question to one question, and I bet the answer to one will also help with the others

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076532/how-does-sbrk-work-in-c

Comment: @MikayelSmbatyan Hold on, you cannot compare the two values from different runs, can you? Are there any guarantees on what `srbk` return address corresponds to "zero allocated memory"?

Comment: Actually 4MB allocations are [above the threshold for mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128587/why-does-malloc-rely-on-mmap-starting-from-a-certain-threshold) so you could also expect those to not move the break at all.

Comment: @teapot418, that explains a lot. I decreased the blockSize to 4KB (less than 128KB) and the program break started to oscillate regardless iostream is included or not.

I'll take your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, yes I know, I put volatile before "char* ptr" earlier then removed but forgot to remove the cast in free. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you add a cast in the call to `free`? And if you insist on using a cast, why `char*` when `free` gets a `void*`?

Comment: @Gerhardh, it was answered literally in the comment before yours. Also, please, stay in the scope of topic. The written cast has nothing to do with the question and can't affect to the outcome.

Comment: `sbrk`/`brk` seem to have been obsolete for more than 2 decades. Why would you use them? If you want to test C++,  learn to write a well designed C++ program first. The gain would be shorter debug cycle and faster code than C. There are lots of invisible enhancements to the core, library and programming style that make this possible.

Comment: @Red.Wave, thanks for advice, didn't need it though. Currently I'm exploring linux kernel internals and linux system programming.

Comment: prepending `#include <iostream>` to a c++ program (you cannot do to a plain C one) that uses only `stdio.h` functions is of no use at all... You'd better to use iostream functions and operators instead the deprecated C counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

As @teapot418 stated

> Actually 4MB [allocations are above the threshold for mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128587/why-does-malloc-rely-on-mmap-starting-from-a-certain-threshold) so you could
> also expect those to not move the break at all.